# Can't assign array to another array

Tags: python

I can't assign an array to another array with for loop. Below is my code sample.

```
df = pd.read_csv('20-newsgroups-ciphertext-challenge/train.csv')
data_1 = df.query('difficulty==1')
X = data_1.iloc[:,-2]
y = data_1.iloc[:,-1]

def tokenize(text): 
    return text.split("1")

data = X
print(type(data))
print(type(X))
for i in range(len(X)):
    data[i]=tokenize(X[i])
```

Below is the error code. I don't understand anything from it.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-4637ad724b98> in <module>
     19 print(type(X))
     20 for i in range(len(X)):
---> 21     data[i]=tokenize(X[i])
     22 
     23 #print(data.head)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    765         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    766         try:
--> 767             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    768 
    769             if not is_scalar(result):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3116         try:
   3117             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3118                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3119         except KeyError as e1:
   3120             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

I am newbie for python and this seems very easy situation here but I would appreciate for solution. 
**I want X array to be tokenized and assign it to data array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, `KeyError` means you're accessing a key (index) that doesn't exist in that list.

On top of that, I believe you could simplify this code:

```py
for i in range(len(X)):
    data[i]=tokenize(X[i])
```

By doing this:

```py
data = [tokenize(i) for i in X]
```

Comment: @Sukru Great, glad to help! :) Could you please mark the answer as the correct one, so people can refer to it in the future? Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Print off `i` and `X[i]` in the loop instead of sending it to `tokenize()` function: `KeyError` means that you cannot access the `ith` element of `X`.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

the way you are iterating your dataframe is wrong

```
for i in data.columns :         
    data[i] = data[i].apply(lambda x: tokenize(x))
```

you don't even need X